# How to detect if the mouse is over  the context menu

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have some mechanism to hide mouse when application works.

But now I added a context menu for the main window form. So when mouse is under the context menu it hides mouse always.

**How to detect if the mouse is over the context menu?**

Thank you for any clue!

P.S.

This code hides mouse when app works

```
  void CursorTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan delta = DateTime.Now.Subtract(this.CursorLastMoveTime);
            if (delta.TotalSeconds > 3)
            {
                CursorTimer.Stop();
                Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.None;
            }
        }
```

Comment: By "under," do you mean "over?"  How do you hide the mouse when the application "works?"

Comment: @DanPuzey pls see my question I just updated it.

Comment: This is not a good way to tell if the application "works" (depending on what you mean by that word) - if the user leaves the mouse alone (for example, to type on the keyboard) their pointer will disappear!

Comment: @DanPuzey Sorry, so how to detect if the mouse is over the context menu?

Comment: what *do* you mean by "works?"  Because your code as posted only reacts to the user's action - it doesn't react to anything the application is doing (unless you're also disabling the mouse!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.aspx) control has a property [`IsMouseOver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ismouseover.aspx) (as do all other UI controls).  You can use that to detect when the mouse is over the menu.

Answer (score 3):

Just a thought, but why not 
stop you timer and Show your mouse
when the context menu is open.
Then start the timer and hide your mouse
When the context menu closes

Comment: Good clue brother! I do the same thing with popup windows I have got there. Yeah!